# Парсинг статистики с сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Как мне немножко подкорректировать парсинг, чтобы сделать под себя

Вот на данный момент у меня такой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse():
    URL = 'https://news.google.com/covid19/map?hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU:ru'
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': '' # В коде есть
    }

    response = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'tZjT9b')
    comps = []

    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            'confirmed': item.find('div', class_ = 'fNm5wd qs41qe').get_text(strip = True),
            'deaths': item.find('div', class_ = 'fNm5wd gZvxhb').get_text(strip = True),
            'recovered': item.find('div', class_ = 'fNm5wd ckqIZ').get_text(strip = True)
        })

    for comp in comps:
        print(comp['confirmed'])
        print(comp['deaths'])
        print(comp['recovered'])

parse()
```

При выполнении этого кода я получаю вот такое:

```
Подтвержденные случаи3 274 747
Выздоровело1 023 911
Умерло233 792
```

Вопрос первый:

1. Как мне сделать отступы, чтобы не было слитно(хотя у меня strip=True) и сделать числа вот в таком формате: 3.000.000
2. Как мне вывод сделать таким:

```
Заболевших: 3.274.747
Выздоровевших: 1.023.911
Умерших: 233.792
```

Comment: В параметрах лучше не ставить пробелы в ` = `: `item.find('div', class_='fNm5wd qs41qe').get_text(strip=True)`. Еще у вас перепутаны умершие и выздоровевшие :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было до конкретного элемента с счетчиком добраться, для простоты кода использовал `css-селектор`.

Еще, я упростил код, убрав лишние циклы, список и словарь:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse():
    URL = 'https://news.google.com/covid19/map?hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU:ru'
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'
    }
    def _get_num(item) -> str:
        return re.sub(r'\s+', '.', item.get_text(strip=True))

    response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    item = soup.find('div', class_='tZjT9b')
    confirmed = _get_num(item.select_one('div.fNm5wd.qs41qe > div.UvMayb'))
    deaths = _get_num(item.select_one('div.fNm5wd.ckqIZ > div.UvMayb'))
    recovered = _get_num(item.select_one('div.fNm5wd.gZvxhb > div.UvMayb'))

    print("Заболевших:   ", confirmed)
    print("Выздоровевших:", recovered)
    print("Умерших:      ", deaths)

parse()
```

Результат:

```
Заболевших:    3.276.373
Выздоровевших: 1.024.529
Умерших:       233.998
```

Comment: Без точек выводится почему-то.. 


Заболевших:    3 303 296
Выздоровевших: 1 039 588
Умерших:       235 290

Comment: @DmitriyMakarov, странно, у меня с точками. Обновил ответ, замену сделал через регулярку

Comment: Теперь все норм. Спасибо большое. =)

Comment: @DmitriyMakarov, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 1):

Ну на скорую руку чисто ради вывода:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    URL = 'https://news.google.com/covid19/map?hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU:ru'

    response = requests.get(URL)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    cells = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'fNm5wd'})

    for param in cells:
        header = param.find('div', class_='RbBDcc')
        value = param.find('div', class_='UvMayb')
        print(header.text, re.sub(r'\s+', '.', value.text))


# Подтвержденные случаи 3.276.373
# Выздоровело 1.024.529
# Умерло 233.998
```